# Walter’s wonky watch

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle

Walter sticks to a strict schedule each weekday. He pays close attention to his digital watch, but it's not an ordinary watch.

Here is his typical day in order:

> Each morning at sun, his alarm goes off and he rolls out of bed.
> After a fifteen minute shower, breakfast, and a commute, he arrives to work at zoo, right on the hour.
> For lunch break, he makes scrambled eggs, always cooked by pans.
> Then he goes for a quick jog around park.
> In the afternoon, he has a nap rest break.
> After work, it’s time for a quick card game: it’s uno.
> Less than an hour later, at spa, he relaxes for a bit.
> Then zap – it’s time for dinner.
> It’s always tough getting the kids to bed; their bedtime is war.

One day at work, a co-worker asked Walter what time it was. He checked his watch and replied “It's now.”

What time was it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is**

> $3:09$

> The digits are represented by letters. zoo being an exact hour tells us that $o=0$. The four digit times pans and park say that $p=1$ and $a=2$.
>  $r,n,u\le5$ because they appear as ten minute digits. $r>n$ from the lunch break and $s=u+1$ because spa is within an hour of uno. This gives $3,4,5,6=n,r,u,s$.
>  $k,z,w\ge7$. $s<z<w$ from the first two lines and last two lines. $z=s+2$ because 15 minutes after sun (653) is before zoo (800). Then $w>z$ and $w=9$ leaving $k=7$.

Comment: I tried to put line breaks in the explanation but then could not get the spoiler marking to work.

Comment: Use <br> tags inside spoilers without pressing Enter.